# date pipe error - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined' when upgraded to Angular 11

Tags: angular, date, pipe, currency

I upgraded my Angular app from v10 to v11.

It uses some std (not custom) pipes - date, currency, uppercase etc.

The date and currency ones are now giving me errors. For example:

```
core.js:5980 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

I'm just importing the CommonModule for the std pipes as before:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

Comment: Can you provide the component's ts and html code where that pipe is implemented? It's hard to say without it.

Comment: in my template : Date: {{ today | date }},
in my TS: today = Date();

Worked ok in Angular 10, now all the pipes that use locale are giving this error. Others like uppercase work ok.

Comment: If I'm not wrong all standart pipes are a part of the `BrowserModule`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem when i upgraded Angular version from 8.2 to 9, any news on this issue?

Comment: For tests it is also worth to check if `import TranslateTestingModule` is present

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that I had this in my app.module.ts:

```
{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useFactory: (translate: TranslateService) => {
        switch (translate.currentLang) {
            case "en":
            case "en_GB":
                registerLocaleData(localeEN)
                break;
            case "es":
            case "es_ES":
                registerLocaleData(localeES)
                break;
            default:
                registerLocaleData(localeEN)
                break;
        }
        return translate.currentLang;
    },
    deps: [TranslateService]
},
```

But `return translate.currentLang;` was `undefined` and returning `undefined` was what was causing this error. So changing it to `return translate.currentLang != undefined ? translate.currentLang : "en";` solved the problem.